# A commutative ring with an ideal $I$ such that $I=I^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring with an ideal $I$ such that $I=I^2$. I have to show that $R=\widetilde{I}\oplus I$ for some ideal $\widetilde{I}$ of $R$.

One attempt that I made was to show that the short exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow I\rightarrow R\rightarrow R/I\rightarrow 0$$
is split, but I couldn't make a progress. I have no clue how to use the condition $I=I^2$. Could you help me with this?

Comment: It is exact, but how will that help you?

Comment: @Displayname Sorry. meant to be 'split'

Comment: If $I=(a)$ is principal, then there exists a unit $u\in A$ such that $a^2=au$. Here, $\widetilde I=(u-a)$ works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not true in general. Consider the ring $R=\mathbb{Q}[x,x^{1/2},x^{1/4},x^{1/8},\dots]$ as a subring of the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, and let $I$ be the ideal $\langle x,x^{1/2},\dots\rangle$ of $R$. Then $I^2=I$ since $x^{1/{2^k}}=(x^{1/2^{k+1}})^2\in I^2$ for each $k$. But $R$ is an integral domain, so $\tilde{I}\cap I\neq\{0\}$ for any non-zero ideal $\tilde{I}\leqslant R$.

However, if $I$ is finitely generated then the result does hold. Indeed in that case we can apply Nakayama's lemma to obtain an element $a\in I$ such that $ab=b$ for every $b\in I$; in particular this means that (i) $I\subseteq \langle a\rangle$, hence $I=\langle a\rangle$, and (ii) that $a^2=a$. Now by Kenta's argument in the comments of your post we are done, as we can simply take $\tilde{I}=\langle 1-a\rangle$.

Comment: This is a nice answer! I wonder if the statement holds under noetherian hypotheses.

Comment: @KentaS indeed it does! :) in fact as long as $I$ is finitely generated the result holds, and something stronger holds: if $I$ is a finitely generated idempotent ideal in a commutative ring then $I$ is principal and generated by an idempotent; you can prove this by Nakayama's lemma